# Is there a way to prevent source files starting with a new line

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint

Using eslint, is it possible to configure a rule to prevent source files starting with a newline?.

Looking around, thought padding-line-between-statements might have been the answer but it does not have a sof / eof option in there :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the rule [`no-multiple-empty-lines`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-multiple-empty-lines) with option `maxBOF` set to 0, e.g.:

```json
{
  ...
  no-multiple-empty-lines: ["error", { max: 2, maxBOF: 0 }]
  ...
}
```